# Excel VBA - Compile Err- Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to code an excel button to reference a value in Column AX Row 2, enter that reference into a field in our business system(IBM), and if it finds a trim at the coordinates matching the trim from Column AX Row 2, to enter that value into the same sheet in column F row 2, then move to the next row and repeat until the row is blank.

I've tried changing to For Next and adjusting code but can't figure out where I am stuck

```
Dim HE As Object
Set HE = CreateObject("BZWhll.WhllObj") 'BlueZone

Dim ExcelTaxID As String
Dim IBMTaxID As String
Dim IBMPvd As String
Dim EachRow As Integer

    AppActivate UseIBM1
    EachRow = 2
    Do While EachRow <> ""

        ExcelTaxID = Trim(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet("ShrPntTransfer").Column("AX").row("EachRow").Value)

        HE.CurrentHost.PutText "BPIQ", 1, 1
        Utilities.PressKey "ENTER", False, UseIBM1, "01", , "YES", "BUTTONS"
        HE.CurrentHost.PutText "5", 22, 12
        Utilities.PressKey "ENTER", False, UseIBM1, "02", , "YES", "BUTTONS"
        HE.CurrentHost.PutText ExcelTaxID, 9, 2
        Utilities.PressKey "ENTER", False, UseIBM1, "03", , "YES", "BUTTONS"

        IBMTaxID = Trim(UseIBM1, 7, 8, 9)

            If ExcelTaxID = IBMTaxID Then
                IBMPvd = Trim(UseIBM1, 7, 35, 6)
                Sheets("ShrPntTransfer").Column("F").row("EachRow").cell.Value = IBMPvd
                ActionEntry = ActionEntry & "Provider Number Recorded"
            Else
                Sheets("ShrPntTransfer").Column("F").row("EachRow").cell.Value = "Provider Not Found"
            End If

            Utilities.PressTwoKeys "SHIFT", "F12", True, UseIBM2, "03", , "YES", "BUTTONS"

        EachRow = EachRow + 1
    Loop
```

Compile Error: wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Comment: `.Column("F").row("EachRow")` >> `.Columns("F").Rows(EachRow)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one could simplify the reference from `column(x).row(y)`  to use either with Range() or Cells() and `EachRow` is a variable and should be unquoted:

So:

```
Trim(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet("ShrPntTransfer").Column("AX").row("EachRow").Value)
```

Becomes

```
Trim(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ShrPntTransfer").Cells(EachRow,"AX").Value)
```

And

```
Sheets("ShrPntTransfer").Column("F").row("EachRow").cell.Value = IBMPvd
```

Becomes

```
Worksheets("ShrPntTransfer").Cells(EachRow,"F").Value = IBMPvd
```

Comment: It does work if you add the `s` and unquote the `EachRow`, but certainly not a common method.

Comment: @TimWilliams really?  Wow did not think it would.

Comment: Well a Column is a Range and a Range has rows so...  I did have to check though.

Comment: I can see the logic, and "learnt me" my new thing today. cool.

Comment: Congrats on the 100.000 :)